# Trying to communicate with the external ip into my docker consul

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, consul

I am new for docker and consul. I have created the 4 instances in AWS. I have added the use of the following instance.

First Instance - Server 1

Second Instance - Server 2

Third Instance - Server 3

Fourth Instance - Server 4

This instance having the ubuntu 18.04 OS. I am trying to implement an auto-discovery concept using consul.

I have done the following steps.

I have installed the docker in my four instances using the below link https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

And pulling the consul image using the below link

https://hub.docker.com/_/consul?tab=description

I have checked on 'Running Consul for Development'. Its working fine for all the instances.

Server 1:

I am trying to run on consul agent in client mode. It's showing below error.

```
sudo docker run -d --net=host -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"leave_on_terminate": true}' consul agent -bind=<external ip> -retry-join=<root agent ip>
```

> external ip - I have given on server1 private IP.
>
> root agent ip - I have given on bootstrap server private IP.

Output:
I got the 64 letter key. EG:

> b93b160ef52b9203d67bb6db27793963dc419276145f4c247c9ba4e2bd6deb03

But that reference sites having a different response.

dig @bootstrap_server_private_ip -p 8600 consul.service.consul

It's showing on connection timed out an error.[connection timed out error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBVoZ.jpg)

Comment: format command and text

Comment: Have you checked your AWS security group for any defined rules that allow all the instances to communicate with each other using their private IP? If not create a rule for the same and add all the instances in that group.

Comment: @Thilak I have added the AWS security group rules. https://ibb.co/1GVwmJ0

Comment: From your screenshot, I couldn't find the respective security group for each instance. But you could create one security group to allow all traffic (both inbound and outbound) internally using [CIDR format](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) (if Applicable). Don't forget to add those security group in all the instances. Once done do a `telnet` to verify the connectivity

Comment: Thank you for reply @Thilak. now I have changed the security group based on the CIDR format. I have tried to verify on telnet. It's showing the error **telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused**.

Comment: Whether all instances that you are trying to telnet are part of that security group?

Comment: @Thilak I have changed the security groups on all the servers. All the servers I got the same error. **telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused** .

Comment: @Boopathi what is exact `telnet` command that you are using to test connectivity?

Comment: I have referred on this site. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-consul-cluster-18-04-lts/  Now I got the solution.